# GitHub Action nektos/act command not found

Tags: yaml, nuget, github-actions

I am new in github actions and I'm trying to migrate some ADO pipelines.
I define the following triggers and jobs:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - development
jobs:
  check:
    name: 'Check'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Check out repository code'
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: 'Nuget Tool Installer'
        uses: nuget/setup-nuget@v1.1.1
      - run: nuget restore MyProject.csproj -PackagesDirectory ./mydirectory/output
```

When I triggered the action with ***act pull_request***, I get the following output:

> [xxxxx]   Start image=node:16-buster-slim
> [xxxxx]     docker pull image=node:16-buster-slim platform= username= forcePull=true
> [xxxxx]     docker create image=node:16-buster-slim platform= entrypoint=["tail" "-f" "/dev/null"] cmd=[]
> [xxxxx]     docker run image=node:16-buster-slim platform= entrypoint=["tail" "-f" "/dev/null"] cmd=[]
> [xxxxx]   ☁  git clone 'https://github.com/nuget/setup-nuget' # ref=v1.1.1
> [xxxxx]   ☁  git clone 'https://github.com/microsoft/setup-msbuild' # ref=v1.1
> [xxxxx] ⭐ Run Main Check out repository code
> [xxxxx]     docker cp src=C:\Users\xxxxx. dst=/mnt/c/Users/xxxxx
> [xxxxx]   ✅  Success - Main Check out repository code
> [xxxxx] ⭐ Run Main Nuget Tool Installer
> [xxxxx]     docker cp src=C:\Users\xxxxx.cache\act/nuget-setup-nuget@v1.1.1/ dst=/var/run/act/actions/nuget-setup-nuget@v1.1.1/
> [xxxxx]     docker exec cmd=[node /var/run/act/actions/nuget-setup-nuget@v1.1.1/dist/index.js] user= workdir=
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::Found NuGet version: 6.4.0
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::isExplicit: 6.4.0
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::explicit? true
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::checking cache: /opt/hostedtoolcache/nuget.exe/6.4.0/x64
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::not found
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::Downloading https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v6.4.0/nuget.exe
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::Destination /tmp/662b0c06-5dea-40d4-b8e9-f351b5c188b1
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::download complete
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::Caching tool nuget.exe 6.4.0 x64
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::source file: /tmp/662b0c06-5dea-40d4-b8e9-f351b5c188b1
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::destination /opt/hostedtoolcache/nuget.exe/6.4.0/x64
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::destination file /opt/hostedtoolcache/nuget.exe/6.4.0/x64/nuget.exe
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::finished caching tool
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::nuget.exe cache path: /opt/hostedtoolcache/nuget.exe/6.4.0/x64.
> [xxxxx]     ::debug::Creating dummy 'nuget' script. | Installed nuget.exe version 6.4.0
> [xxxxx]   ✅  Success - Main Nuget Tool Installer
> [xxxxx]   ⚙  ::set-env:: NUGET=/opt/hostedtoolcache/nuget.exe/6.4.0/x64/nuget.exe
> [xxxxx]   ⚙  ::set-output:: nuget-version=6.4.0
> [xxxxx]   ⚙  ::add-path:: /opt/hostedtoolcache/nuget.exe/6.4.0/x64
> [xxxxx] ⭐ Run Main nuget restore MyProject.csproj -PackagesDirectory ./MyProjectFolder/output
> [xxxxx]     docker exec cmd=[bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail /var/run/act/workflow/2] user= workdir= | /opt/hostedtoolcache/nuget.exe/6.4.0/x64/nuget: 2: /opt/hostedtoolcache/nuget.exe/6.4.0/x64/nuget: mono: not found
> [xxxxx]   ❌  Failure - Main nuget restore MyProject.csproj -PackagesDirectory ./MyProjectFolder/output
> [xxxxx] exitcode '127': command not found, please refer to https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/107 for more information

As the container is still available in docker, I opened a terminal session and attempt to execute the **nuget** command. It is not available. Do you know what I am doing wrong? I beleive that it will became available with nuget/setup-nuget@v1.1.1

Comment: It's missing the whole .NET runtime on the image. Maybe using `actions/setup-dotnet@3` will do the trick. But the image for ACT only contains a very limited number of tools in the default image. You'll have to install just about everything on it to run a non-node workload.

Comment: When migrating from Azure Pipelines to GitHub Actions, be sure to check out the GitHub actions Importer: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/automated-migrations/automating-migration-with-github-actions-importer

Comment: @jessehouwing is dotnet required? Based on https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-nuget-exe-for-use-with-actions it should work without it.
Also I tried adding it and I get the following dotnet_install: Error: curl (recommended) or wget are required to download dotnet. Install missing prerequisite to proceed.
even when I added the following action https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-curl before

Comment: You can see in the log: `mono: not found` that's nuget calling mono to perform the restore on its behalf. Now that the packages are all in the project files, it's actually mono and msbuild that perform the real work. `github-action-for-curl` runs in its own docker container, so it doesn't install `curl` on the runner at all.

Comment: You probably need to apt-get install a boatload of additional things onto the image to make it usable and to make it look remotely like a true hosted runner. The Hosted runner is 18GB in size, this image is tiny in comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an error on act version which doesn't matter which image you specify, it always take the slim which lacks a lot of components. After updating to version 0.2.44 the issue got fixed and I could run the action with the required image